# Intersections in the coordinate axes of the tangent

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the equation of the curve such that the product of the intersections in the coordinate axes of
the tangent at any point of it, is a constant k . Solve this equation.

I have tried to do this:  If the tangent equation in the point $(x,y(x)$ of curve $y(x)$ is $L: \hat{y} - y = y'(x)(\hat{x} - x)$ then his intersections in the coordinate axes are
$$ \hat{y}=\left( x - \frac{y}{y'}\right)$$
$$ \hat{x}=\left(y - xy'\right) $$

and the equation is $\hat{x}\hat{y}=k $, or in terms of $y$

$$ \left( x - \frac{y}{y'}\right)\left(y - xy'\right)=k  $$

But, I don't know how to solve this equation

Comment: You have been answering a ton of questions in the last minutes, are these homework ? Also some questions of yours have been answered or commented at, but you had not shown any action.

Comment: Is a list of problem for study. I posted three of them, not a ton, how you said, because I do not know how to solve them.

Comment: One of them has been answered and commented on though without any sign of action from you. This is why I mentioned it.